# find the inverse function.

Tags: functions

So $f$ and $g$ are both functions from $Q \rightarrow Q$ for every $x \in Q$. It is given that $g(x) = f(3x + 2)$, where $f$ is a reversible function.

I need to prove that $g$ is reversible as well and show that the reversible function for $g$ is as follows:
for every $y \in Q$   $g^{−1}(y) = (f−1(y) - 2 ) / 3$

I had no problems proving that g is indeed reversible but I am stuck at showing how to get to $g^{−1}(y) = (f−1(y) - 2 ) / 3$

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u,v\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $g^{-1}(v)=u$. Then

$$v=g(u)=f(3u+2)$$

As $f$ is invertible,

$$f^{-1}(v)=3u+2$$

$$u=\frac{f^{-1}(v)-2}{3}$$

$$g^{-1}(v)=\frac{f^{-1}(v)-2}{3}$$